# How to strip HTML from text using JavaScript but keep a space between each line?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140708/1526396) to strip HTML from text.

This is how it works:

```JavaScript
function strip(html){
   let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
   return doc.body.textContent || "";
}
```

If I have some HTML like this:

```HTML
This is the first line<br>
This is the second line<br>
This is the third line
```

It strips out the line breaks, and creates text like this:

```HTML
This is the first lineThis is the second lineThis is the third line
```

But as you can see when it removes the line breaks there is no space left between each sentence. This is not how I want it to look.

How do I retain a space between each line (or sentence) after it strips the HTML?

I want it to look something like this:

```HTML
This is the first line This is the second line This is the third line
```

Comment: Your example input appears to contain carriage returns in addition to line breaks. Additional code would be needed to handle both and still output the expected single line with spaces.

Comment: @Yogi have a look at my answer. That html also contains the newlines, yet the original `textContent` returns no whitespace there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, but you'd have to manipulate the doc before geting the text content:

```js
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('This is the first line<br>\
This is the second line<br>\
This is the third line', 'text/html');

console.log(doc.body.textContent);

doc.body.querySelectorAll('br')                      // Get all <br> elements
  .forEach(br => br.after(doc.createTextNode(' '))); // And spaces after them 

console.log(doc.body.textContent);
```

I'm using `querySelectorAll` to get all linebreaks, and then I add a space text node after each one.

Comment: This answer is great because I just realized I also needed to have spaces after `</li>` and `<div>` elements, and it allows me to easily add those. For anyone else reading if you need spaces after other things you can add them like this `.querySelectorAll('br, li, div')`. That example will put a space after all `<br>`, `<li>`, and `<div>` elements.